# URL paths taxonomyterm/pagename instead of content/pagename

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I've set up a vocabulary with some terms. I've created some new pages and tagged with the newly created terms. However, the node urls are in the form of content/pagename and I would like them to be taxonomyterm/pagename instead.

What do I need to do in order to get the urls to display in the taxonomyterm/pagename format?

Drupal 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under */admin/config/search/path/patterns* you can change the default pattern for the content type from `content/[node:title]` and set the pattern to `[node:field-tag]/[node:title]`. It is probably a good idea to restrict field_tag to a single value, and to make it required if you are going to use a pattern like this.

Comment: Thank you. Should I perhaps create a new content type for pages with tags? @Triskelion

Comment: That would probably be a good idea.